# How to do a For loop with letters in cmd file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, directory

I have a problem in .cmd file. hope u can help me

I made an algorith that copy all the files and subfolders (xcopy), then paste it to a new directory.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
:menu

if not exist G:\ (goto 1)

md "C:\Users\x\Documents\test"
xcopy "G:\*.*" test /e /i /h /k
cls

:1
if not exist H:\ (goto 2)
md "C:\Users\x\Documents\test"
xcopy "H:\*.*" test /e /i /h /k
cls
```

I know this could be better, but for now, my problem is how can I do a "for loop with letters" and no numbers. Because It would be more shortly if i use a simple for loop than an extensive menu with all drive letters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%d in (g h) do if exist "%%d:\" (
 md "C:\Users\%%d\Documents\test"
 xcopy "%%d:\*.*" test /e /i /h /k
 goto done
)
echo drives not found
:done
```

just expand `g h` to include any drives you like.